# Logic behind choosing weight for weighted loss calculation?

Tags: face-recognition, image-recognition, loss-function, vision, cross-entropy

What is the general logic behind choosing the weight for calculating weighted sigmoid cross-entropy loss, or for any weighted loss in case of an imbalanced dataset? The problem domain is based on vision/image classification.

Answer (score 2):

A good reference would be this CVPR '19 paper:
[*"Class-Balanced Loss Based on Effective Number of Samples"*](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2019/papers/Cui_Class-Balanced_Loss_Based_on_Effective_Number_of_Samples_CVPR_2019_paper.pdf). In the paper, they've used an re-weighting scheme that uses the effective number of samples for each-class to re-balance the loss for handling inter-class imbalance issues. 
You could also refer a [Medium](https://towardsdatascience.com/handling-class-imbalanced-data-using-a-loss-specifically-made-for-it-6e58fd65ffab) article explaining the same research work.

Comment: A very good starting point, thanks. But why is the norm of weighting is set to the inverse of class support or inverse of the square root of class support?